# caretMode in QRegExp::indexIn, lastIndexIn. What's the meaning and purpose?

Tags: c++, regex, qt

I'm learning the Qt and the Regular Expressions.
Hence I read the documentation for QRegExp of Qt 5.4.

I noticed that the indexIn() function appears many times in the detailed description.

But I just cannot understand the meaning of the caretMode.
Here is the documentation section:

> ```
> int QRegExp::indexIn(const QString & str, int offset = 0,
>                        CaretMode caretMode = CaretAtZero) const
> ```
>
> Attempts to find a match in str from position offset (0 by default).
>   If offset is -1, the search starts at the last character; if -2, at
>   the next to last character; etc.
>
> Returns the position of the first match, or -1 if there was no match.
>
> The caretMode parameter can be used to instruct whether ^ should match
>   at index 0 or at offset.
>
> You might prefer to use QString::indexOf(), QString::contains(), or
>   even QStringList::filter(). To replace matches use QString::replace().

If the offset is not 0 and the `caretMode = CaretAtZero` and the regexp has a caret, what will the regexp find?

Comment: `^` matches at "start of input". `indexIn` starts searching in the middle of the string - you get to choose whether or not the starting position should count as "start of input" for the purpose of matching against `^`. In the example in your last sentence, the regular expression like `^sometext` won't match and `indexIn` will return -1.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Please post that as an answer.